# MySQL: get how many entrys for each id on each date?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table with an associate_id and date fields. I want to get how many the associates have for each date. For example if this was my Table:

```
date    associate_id
2009-07-08  10
2009-07-08  113
2009-07-09  113
2009-07-09  113
```

I want results like this:

```
date    associate_id    per_date
2009-07-08  10              1
2009-07-08  113             1
2009-07-09  113             2
```

I tried this but it wasn't right:

```
SELECT 
            associate_id, date, COUNT(date) as per_date
            FROM 
            tracking
            GROUP BY
            date 
            ORDER BY
            date
```

Also I am sure it needs to be a separate call but I also need a list of the DISTINCT associate_id's that were pulled.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select date, associate_id, count(*) as per_date
From tracking
Group By assoicate_id, date
Order by date
```